# ASPNET Core/EF Core App on Top of Net46

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have an MVC6 website which has to run on top of the full net framework because it relies on various libraries which have not been updated to support Net Core.

I think I may be misconfiguring the project.json file. Here's what I have:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Serilog": "2.2.1",
    "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": "3.0.1",
    "Serilog.Sinks.Literate": "2.0.0",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.2.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.1.1",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.2.1",
    "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs": "1.1.2",
    "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "3.2.1",
    "UploadFramework": "1.0.0-*",
    "ConnellDataCore": "1.0.0-*",
    "ConnellData": "1.0.0-*",
    "System.IO.Compression": "4.1.0",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.281"
},

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

All of the projects that this one depends on are built on top of Net46. There project.json files all have entries like:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Configuration": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
```

although in this particular example I incorporated the frameworkAssemblies entry because I need access to ConfigurationManager (and if that's not the right way to solve that problem, please advise).

Is this the right way to configure an ASPNET Core/EF Core app to run on top of Net46? If not, what do I need to change?

**Additional Info**

The problems I'm running into involve the System.IO.Compression assembly. Specifically, what happened is that my solution built, but whenever the website tried to access a ZipArchive, it crashed. Because the System.IO.Compression.dll wasn't deployed to the site's bin directory (interestingly, System.IO.Compression.Zip.dll **was** deployed, but it's not useful with System.IO.Compression.dll).

I "solved" that problem by manually copying System.IO.Compression to the website's bin folder. But that manually copied DLL doesn't get deployed to Azure when the site is published, so the Azure-based site exhibits that same crashing problem.

In trying to solve this I dug around through all the various projects and checked the file versions of the System.IO.Compression DLLs. And I discovered an oddity: the System.IO.Compression DLL being included in my subsidiary projects (on which the website depends) are being deployed from the NetCore assembly cache, not the standard Net4.6 cache.

I don't know what this means. But I think it may be related to the problem I'm encountering.

So my goal is, somehow, to ensure that >>no<< project deploys any assembly from Net Core.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. I suspect the issue involves some reference, perhaps ASPNET Core itself, which is insisting on/defaulting to using the Net Core assemblies. But I don't know how to tell it not to.

Comment: Why do you think you are misconstruing it? Are there any errors? Does it build and publish fine? (I can't see anything wrong with it, all dependencies and frameworks are in the right place)

Comment: LOL! I rarely post config questions like this, so my habit of showing which line of code caused an error didn't kick in...because the problem(s) aren't related to a particular line of code. Thanx for the feedback, and I've edited my question to provide more context.

Comment: may be helped to you : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/

Answer (score 0):

The dll not being copied isn't related to .net core, I'm not sure what the problem with that is, the dll isn't copied because there are no direct references to it in your code.  The System.IO.Compression.Zip.dll is copied because somewhere in your code you are instantiating an object or calling a static method from that dll.

When entity framework 6 shipped they moved the SqlServer provider into a seperate dll and things broke all over the place because since no one had direct references to it in code it wasn't getting deployed.

Rob Lang has an interesting read on his [adventures](http://robsneuron.blogspot.nl/2013/11/entity-framework-upgrade-to-6.html) and eventual solution:

```
var ensureDLLIsCopied = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;
```

I've also seen simular issues with all of the SqlServer Data Type dlls when deploying an application with local reports, there I took a different approach and referenced the dlls directly in the web project (there were so many) and set them all to copy local true, I believe that as long as the dlls are refrerenced in the project being published or deployed they will also be copied into the output folder, but if they're referenced by a class library that's referenced by the project being published/deployed they won't.